# Oracle: разбить запись на несколько строк

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Есть запись вида:

```
111 бланк1 бланк2
```

Мне необходимо разбить ее на две записи при выборке:

```
111   бланк1
111   бланк2
```

Что-то пока идей никаких

Comment: Уточните задачу. Что из себя представляют исходные данные, какие разделители между символами, по какому принципу определяется, что `111` повторяется, а остаток строки - должен биться на части. В такой постановке идей может быть слишком много.

Comment: В остатке строки всегда 2 записи или больше?

Comment: Это одна колонка или 3 разных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION ALL` должен помочь в такой ситуации

```
select column1, column2 newcolumnname from yourtable
union all
select column1, column3 newcolumnname from yourtable
```

Comment: И как это должно помочь?

Comment: @Viktorov а что не так-то?

Comment: Я подумал, что ТС под записью имеет ввиду строку. Возможно, я заблуждаюсь. 
Но даже, если я заблуждаюсь, то если у ТС 100 строк, то ему написать 200 запросов руками?

Comment: @Viktorov если двести строк, то надо уточнить желаемый результат. А если одну надо взять  из двухсот, то просто дописать условие выборки. Если же там двести столбцов, например, тот тогда ещё варианты ответа образуются (:

Comment: На мой взгляд, ответ будет более качественным и полезным, если сначала разобраться, что хочет ТС. Помочь до конца ему сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Получается, что сейчас Ваш ответ не отвечает на вопрос ТСа, как минимум потому, что не понятно даже, чего хочет ТС

Comment: @Viktorov, не забирайте у меня право на интуицию, пожалуйста. Хоть я и не женщина. С вами согласен

Comment: интуциция работает

Comment: А, так ему `UNPIVOT` нужен был...

Comment: Признаюсь, я шокирован Вашей интуицией. Как думаете, кто выиграет ЧМ ?)

Comment: @Viktorov интуиция подсказывает, что не сборная России)

Answer (score 1):

В одно чтение:

```
select с1, case x when 1 then с2 else с3 end с2 from t
cross join (select 1 x from dual union all select 2 from dual);
```

Answer (score 1):

Универсальное (насколько можно) решение через `UNPIVOT`:

```
with t as (select 111 a, 'бланк1' b, 'бланк2' c from dual)
select a, blanks
  from t
unpivot (blanks for id in (b, c))


         A BLANKS     
---------- -----------
       111 бланк1     
       111 бланк2
```